# javafx (ant) build error: Connot find symbol: Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.Error);

Tags: java, xml, javafx, build

I'm new in javafx. I try to build my procect, where i'll show a Alert but the build faile and show following:

[image: "Error"]

In my ide (eclipse) it's work very well. But if I try to build this project it will faile :((

**Techniqual information:**
JDK: 1.8.0_66
And my standard library in eclipse is setup to jdk

**I solve the problem which is above. But now I get an new problem:**

Please have a look to the following screenshot:
[image: error2]

After a successfull build from the project in javafx8 I'd start my project and I faced with 2 errors (see second picture). Can any one of you help me??

Comment: `Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);`...

Comment: your error message indicates JRE 1.8.025 which is pre-version 1.8.40 which introduced `Alert`...

Comment: That's strange. I don't recognize it. But my jdk is > 1.8.025 how can i solve this problem?

Comment: From the menu, go to "Run" -> "Run Configurations" and check what's under the JRE tab. You might also want to check "Project" -> "Properties" and "Java Build Path".

Comment: Ok thank you. I solved this Problem by changing the path in the build.xml.

Comment: i edited my question, please have a look for it - thkns